# How to post non-post data into session when user logs in

Tags: php, mysql, class, codeigniter, methods

When my users log into the website their first name, last name and ID are missing from the session data because my session data is coded to take post data and submit into the session table in my database.

Because user logs in with email and password in my session data only email appears and nothing else does.

How can I make first name, last name and id appear in my session table in my db? I want to some how grab these details from the database when user is logging in and provide it in my $u_data array so it get's posted upload login success.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Login_Model extends CI_Model {


    public function checkLogin() {

            $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email')); //compare db email to email entered in form
            $this->db->where('password', $this->hashed()); //compare db password to hashed user password
            $query = $this->db->get('users'); //get the above info from 'user' table

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) { //if number of rows returned is 1

            $u_data = array( //new variable with session data
                'user_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($u_data); //send data from variable to db session
            return TRUE;

       } else {
            return FALSE;
       }
 }


   public function hashed() { //hashing method

            // sha1 and salt password
            $password = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password')); //encrypt user password
            $salt = $this->config->item('encryption_key'); //grab static salt from config file

            $start_hash = sha1($salt . $password);
            $end_hash = sha1($password . $salt);
            $hashed = sha1($start_hash . $password . $end_hash);
            return $hashed;
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: @Psychonetics: There are many possibilities.
Have you added the 2 fields in the respective table where you need to store data? And Have you cleared the cache (something like symfony cc to clear the cache so that the changes in DB are reflected)
Have you configured Your CI application to use tables for session? 
Have you started session in your controller?
There are many possibilities. 
If you have done above things then you must google "CI with custom session data" or something like that

Comment: Yep all those things are done. The sessions work fine because when user registers their post data shows in the sessions table.  
When user registers and is automatically logged on, first_name, last_name etc are put into my sessions table in the db. This is because the post data is available from when user fills out the registration form. With login now the only fields available are email and password so the only post data I can grab to put into my sessions table would be email. So that's where I became stuck.

Comment: @Psychonetics : You store the data in a session at first logon, but do you also store it in a more permanent table, like a list of all users?

Comment: Nope doesn't get stored in anything other than the sessions table. I have attached a photo. As you will see there is one column where all my user session data goes into.

Comment: Well i think that your code has line something $this->input->post('first_name') instead of that you can do this way
if ( isset($this->input->post('first_name')) &&  isset($this->input->post('last_name')) ) { $first_name =  $this->input->post('first_name') } else { // get value from DB anyway you will have that value if you query db }
and then change 'first_name' => $first_name. 
I guess you have to fetch user details instead of checking that user exist count

Comment: @Psychonetics: if you don't permanantly store usere data when the user signs up (like the username and password) then that data will not be available to you at a later date without asking for it again.  Since that would be a usability issue, you need to either permanantly store the user data somewhere (eiher in your db or in a cookie, though that is less reliable) or remove the requirement to have/preaent that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved this issue for me. I looked at one of my old questions on here and used my common sense.

I made this edit to my code.

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) { //if number of rows returned is 1

      $user = $query->result();

                $u_data = array( //new variable with session data
                    'user_id' => $user[0]->id,
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'first_name' => $user[0]->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user[0]->last_name,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be as simple as doing something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userdata'] = $u_data;
```

within your CheckLogin method. The session is just a regular PHP array that happens to be automatically preserved for you. You can put anything you want into it, but you do have do put things into it yourself - PHP won't do it for you.

comment followup:

gotcha. So, you simply modify you class to fetch that information from the DB once the login's authenticated. I don't know how your DB class works, but instead of merely checking if there's a matching row, fetch the first/last name, using a query something like this:

```
select firstname, lastname
from users
where email=$email and password=$password
```

If you get a result row, you know it's a valid login, and then you just retrieve the name data. I have no idea how your db class works, but it shouldn't be too hard to get it to do that.

Comment: I may have it wrong, but I think OP is tracking sessions in a DB table - possibly to support multiple front ends, such as for load balancing.  Then again, I may have misread it and s/he really is looking for your answer :)

Comment: When user registers and is automatically logged on, first_name, last_name etc are put into my sessions table in the db. This is because the post data is available from when user fills out the registration form. With login now the only fields available are email and password so the only post data I can grab to put into my sessions table would be email. So that's where I became stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tracking sessions in your DB, two solutions come to mind.

First, you could select the first/last from the user table and insert it into the session table.  This requires changes to your application.

Second, you could set up a view for your application, in which the session table is automatically joined with the appropriate user, but that assumes you already have some unique identifier for which user it is in the session (was that the email address?*).  This solution would not require any changes to the application code, but would require changes to the DB, which may be the preferred method depending upon your deployment requirements (or it may not :) ).

* as a side note, if you're using email addresses for unique identifiers, be aware that some people share email addresses as you decide if this is the right solution for you.

Comment: I was thinking of something along those lines. I would like to use the ID of the user. So when the email address is recognised it then get's the id from the row the email address is in then grabs all the associated data such as first_name, last_name and puts this into the session table. Kind of complicated though as my sessions table has 1 column for all the session data.

Comment: @Psychonetics: then you may either need to refactor your sessions table or make a second sql query.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm working with Auth systems in CodeIgniter I have made it a practice to include the "user" object globally in views, and also globally in my controllers, by fetching the userdata in the constructor, like so...

```
<?php

class My_Controller extends Controller {

    private $the_user;  //global var to store current user data

    function My_Controller() {
        parent::Controller();

        $data->the_user = $this->ion_auth->get_user();       //get user data
        $this->load->vars($data);                  //load into all views as $the_user "$the_user"
        $this->the_user=$data->the_user;         //load into private class variable "$this->the_user"
    }
```

At that point $the_user variable object is available in all views by default AND $this->the_user is always available to controller functions.  It always represents the user currently logged in.

I am using Ion_auth for authentication and fetching the user, so that piece you would have to fill in.

I actually just [constructed a "How-to"](http://jondavidjohn.com/code-design/codeigniter-login-system) to implement extended Controller classes so all the Auth logic is automatically inherited to all "protected" Controllers.